# es6 class: how to omit "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-next

In ES6, is it possible to create local variables and **just reference them directly**, **instead of adding** `this.` in front, like `this.name`.

Example, in the code below, what can I do to make it possible to write `{name}` instead of `{this.name}` all the time. (Adding `this.` in front of variables is a bit cumbersome!)

```jsx
class User extend React.Component {
    name = "Joe";

    render() {
        // is it possible to write {name} instead of {this.name}
        return <div>{name}</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I think that variable will be the same across the entire class, not per-object.

Comment: @ShadowRanger it says `name` is not defined

Comment: At the top of every function that uses it, you could `const { name } = this;` I suppose

Comment: But in general, there's nothing that automatically converts properties to local variables.

Comment: I don't think `this` is cumbersome. It makes your code much more clear. You can easily differentiate between your instance variables and local variables.

Comment: She's probably coming from C++, which puts member variables in the scope of all methods.

Comment: C++ is unusual among OO languages in doing that. Most require you to use special syntax to access member variables.

Comment: Note that `name = "Joe";` is not ES6. @Barmar: Java works like that too.

Comment: so is there anything in ES6 that can create local variables inside a class, like in vanilla javascript `function User(){ var name="joe" }`, then you can just use variable `name` inside that class

Comment: How about `t = this; t.name;` FTW? :)

Answer (score 7):

This is possible with `with` statement, but since it isn't compatible with strict mode, it has no value in modern JS.

There's no way to do this otherwise, and since `this.name` shouldn't be confused with `name` variable , omitting `this` would be a mistake.

If `this.name` in JSX affects readability or is used many times, the property can be destructured:

```
render() {
    const { name } = this;

    return <div>{name}</div>
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that you can only use this for reading properties, you still have to use `this.name` if you want to assign to it.

Comment: so is there anything in ES6 that can create local variables inside a class, like in vanilla javascript `function User(){ var name="joe" }`, then you can just use variable `name` inside that class

Comment: ES6 class is syntactic sugar for a function. You can create a variable in class constructor. It won't be available inside `render` *prototype method*, but it won't also be available in desugared class prototype method, `function User(){ var name="joe" }; User.prototype.render = function () {...}`. And `name` variable is likely worse than `name` class property for extensibility and testability reasons.

Comment: @estus So vanilla and es6 are not equivalent. In vanilla a class method `this.say()` can access local variable `name`, in such manner:  `function User(){ var name="joe"; this.say=function(){console.log(name)} };`. But in ES6, a class method defined as `class User { say=()=>{ console.log(...)} }` can simply not access the local variable defined in the constructor, right? Therefore ES6 and vanilla are not equivalent.

Comment: In order to efficiently use ES6 it's preferable to clearly understood how ES6 code translates to ES5. `say=()=>...` - that's not ES6, it's ES.next [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). It's syntactic sugar for ES6 counterpart, `class User { constructor() { let name="joe"; this.say=()=>...;  } }`. Which can be directly translated to ES5 `function User()...`. And yes, it isn't possible to have a variable in this ES.next example but is possible in ES6, that's the case when syntactic sugar has flaws. And as it was mentioned, using `this` property is beneficial, so stick to it.