# how to omit "this" reference in javascript class?

Tags: javascript

I got a class us ES6 grammar like

```
class Bind {
    a;
    b;
    constructor(a, b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    describe() {
        console.log(this.a);
        console.log(this.b);
    }
}
```

when class goes larger, the "this" reference goes more verbose. Are there any ways to omit the class reference in javascript class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50867834/es6-class-how-to-omit-this-keyword

Comment: "Why do pots have handles? It makes the kitchen so cluttered, especially in a busier kitchen. Any way to omit pot handles?" :) `this` is there for a reason, and the five extra characters don't adversely impact legibility.